# Set color filter not work with custom color

Tags: android, imageview

I have an png image with black color and set it to image view. And I have a color hex `#EFA78E`. Then, I convert hex string to colorInt by

```
int color = Color.parseColor(#EFA78E);
```

After that I set the color to imageview

```
imageView.setColorFilter(color);
```

And it show a transparent image. I already try with all mode of `PorterDuff.Mode` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to show us your code that you tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#EFA78E"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
imageView.setImageResource(yourImage);
```

If it dosn't work, you can also use the `android:tint` attribute in xml to acheive the same.

```
<ImageView
   ... 
   android:tint="#EFA78E"/>
```

Comment: thank for you answer, but I need set color programmatically

Comment: Hi, thank for your updated, but I do like you comment and it not work. I send you the attach resource png. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gcabn63KU1AKFutV5YNbPJhtpd2nOOW1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried using your 'png image' with the same code that i posted as the answer, and it is working fine. Post your code the a screenshot of the result.

Comment: Hi, your code is work well when the image in the normal view. But when I add image in the recyclerview, the bug happen.

Comment: Hi @Vivek, thank for your support. I found the issue. Because I have an container that contain the image view.
`code'

container.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EFA78E");
container.setAlpha(0.5f);

imageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#EFA78E"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
imageView.setImageResource(sourceImage);

`code`

I have to do like that for the container
`code`
container.setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.argb(Math.round(Color.alpha(color) * 0.5f),
                    Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color)));
`code`

And it work.